# How to change workflow without locking an item for non-admin users?

Tags: sitecore-client

I have created a new non-admin user role. Now, I want this user to change the workflow without locking an item.

I have tried setting `RequireLockBeforeEditing` to `false`, but does not work. Also, I want this lock items update to this specific role only.

```
<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="false" />
```